# Alternar resultados de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

excelente día.

Hay alguna manera de alternar los resultados de una consulta SQL de acuerdo a un campo, es decir

tengo los siguientes resultados

```
Id_usuario  Username    id_tipo
Usuiario1   Nombre1     1
Usuiario2   Nombre2     1
Usuiario3   Nombre3     2 
Usuiario4   Nombre4     2
```

La idea seria obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
Id_usuario  Username    id_tipo
Usuiario1   Nombre1       1
Usuiario3   Nombre3       2
Usuiario2   Nombre2       1
Usuiario4   Nombre4       2
```

Obtener de forma alternada por tipo los registros, es eso posible en SQL ¿? y con que sentencias seria la manera correcta de llevarlo acabo
Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Veo que el id cambia pero el nombre no. ¿Eso es correcto o es un error? ¿Podrías poner los datos como texto y no como imagen?

Comment: Si disculpa, es correcto fue un error, si deben alternarse los registros completamente , lo que debe mandar seria la alternación del campo tipo, ¿es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí es posible. Para esto, necesitamos crear una columna (dentro de la consulta) que permita ordenar una fila de cada tipo a la vez. Esto lo podemos hacer con `ROW_NUMBER()` y haciendo que se reinicie en cada tipo. De esta forma, cada fila tendrá un número incremental y tendremos tantos grupos como tipos haya.

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id_tipo ORDER BY Id_usuario) rn
FROM Usuarios
ORDER BY rn, id_tipo;
```

Ahora, el problema es que no queremos que esa columna aparezca, ya que no es parte de nuestra información y solo es una herramienta. Pero no la podemos generar directamente en el `ORDER BY`. Para esto, podemos utilizar un CTE o una tabla derivada (subconsulta). En este caso, dejo el ejemplo de como hacerlo con la CTE.

```
WITH cteUsuarios AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id_tipo ORDER BY Id_usuario) rn
    FROM Usuarios
)
SELECT id_usuario,
    username,
    id_tipo
FROM cteUsuarios
ORDER BY rn, id_tipo;
```

Comment: Perfecto, es justo lo que necesitaba, Muchísimas gracias de verdad, me salvaste de una., excelente día.